# CURL - Getting empty response

Tags: php, curl

I'm facing a problem with CURL. It might be related to SSL.

I had this problem in both local and server. Added the below code in both source files:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

I got the response in local. But not in server. Why?

Comment: This looks like it calls for basic debugging first.What is `curl_error()` saying?

Comment: `curl_error` can tell you why

Comment: Curl_error return "Empty reply from server".